# Re-running a command prompt after termination

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, wget

I'm currently using wget to download off of an archive, but after about 20 minutes, it terminates itself without downloading the rest of the files.
However, every time I launch it, it manages to get through the ones already downloaded, and then a few of the files afterwards. This being the case, I'm making very minor headway.
Is there a prompt I could use to make the prior prompt run again, automatically, after termination?

Answer (score 0):

There is the option `-c` for continue. If the target file is already present, the download is skipped. If the file is partially present, the download is continued.

But you should find out why your downloads terminate.

Comment: I have the -c flag on, so it doesn't download the files I already have. The downloads don't terminate in the middle of them, it's like the command prompt terminates the script after a random number of downloads, with there still being many files left undownloaded. It's awfully bizarre

Comment: And is there any kind of message when it terminates?